# Implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState

Tags: security, electron, sonoma

When I use `npm start` to test my first Electron app on MacOS Sonoma (14.2.1), I get this warning in the Terminal:

> Electron[79515:993116] WARNING: Secure coding is automatically enabled for restorable state! However, not on all supported macOS versions of this application. Opt-in to secure coding explicitly by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState:.

What exactly do I need to do to implement this?

Comment: What version of Electron? There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/40318) about this.

Comment: npm list
    └── electron@28.2.1
The closed issue is for Sonoma 14.0 and Electron 17.0.2, and it does not give any steps on how to solve the problem. The link at the end that describes the vulnerability helpfully ends with "if you write an Objective-C application, please make sure you add -applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: to return TRUE", but this does not help with an Electron application.

Comment: You should read what's on the [PR](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/40296) too.

Comment: Is this what you think I should be reading? "This message doesn't actually indicate there is anything wrong, it's only a single annoying log line that can be ignored "

Comment: Yes but also that someone signaled the bug reappeared on Sonoma 14.2, and that the fix only seems to be possible in electron source code.